# Spring Rest filter Data Chaining

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have a spring Rest web app. And created auth filter. on this layer, I am getting User which is needed at RestController methods. I want to avoid DB request duplication. Is it possible to pass some objects from Filter to RestController Methods as a param?

```
  @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
                     FilterChain chain) throws IOException, 
ServletException {
        String authorization = ((HttpServletRequest) req).getHeader("Authorization");
        DeviceEntity deviceEntity = mDeviceService.byToken(authorization);
        if (deviceEntity != null) {
            if (new Date().before(deviceEntity.getExpireOn())) {
                chain.doFilter(req, res);
            }
        } else {
            ((HttpServletResponse) res).setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
}
```

I want to pass deviceEntity to the next class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/general")
public class RestService {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/ping", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void ping(DeviceEntity de) {
    //                ^^^^^^^^^^
    //i want to have access to this device here
        LOG.info("Ping called");
    }
}
```

I need some way to pass this Device entity to RequestMapped method

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: You can set as an attribute on the `HttpServletRequest` in the `filter` processing and then just recover it from there while reaching the controller, you just need to include the `HttpServletRequest` as a parameter in the `controller` method. There could be other approaches too, but this is the simplest I think